# Python Regular Expressions, finding garbage words in a text file

Tags: python, regex

So far we have this

```
re.findall(r'[+-](?!\d)|(?<!\d)[.]|[^\+\-.\d\w\s]+',str)
```

but it won’t take dots between numbers and `@.%` will take each as a word instead of one word.

First example problem: `15.2.2.2.2.2.` is:

1. `15.2`
2. `2.2`
3. `2.2`

The garbage will not take the dots between those numbers and at the end; what am I missing in the pattern?

---

2<sup>nd</sup> problem: `#.@`

Will be read as

1. `#`
2. `.`
3. `@`

instead of `#.@` ! !!!

Comment: What is your definition of "garbage word"?

Comment: What is the expected output for '15.2.2.2.2.2.', and for '#.@'?

Comment: Garbage word is any of the following:
anything but a number/letters ( +1 +100.2 100.4 are numbers)
so on the string ++1 the garbage word is +
and for the string +1.2.2 the garbage word is . (the 2nd one)

#.@ output should be #.@ , i mean it recieves it as one input
 and not 3 inputs

15.2.2.2.2.2. output is .(2nd one) .(4th one) .(last one)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a really hard time understanding what you are asking. It will help if you edit your question and add in the clarifications from your comment. Also, explain in English, not Python, what you are trying to accomplish. What is your input? What is your desired output? Finally, I don't understand what text you mean by "garbage" and "the second one".

Answer (score 1):

note that `.` will match any letter.  if you want to match a "." (period; full stop; decimal point) then you need `\.`.

also, `5.2.2.2.2.2` can match the numbers `5.2` `.2`  `.2` `.2` `.2` so contains no garbage.

more generally, i think what you are trying to do is impossible with regular expressions.  i don't have a proof, but i am pretty sure you would do better matching words and numbers, and then marking what is left as garbage:

```
>>> everything = re.compile(r'(?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?|[+-]?\.\d+)|\w+|(.)') 
>>> everything.findall('123  . &^%! a.b  3.14')
['', ' ', '.', ' ', '&', '^', '%', '!', ' ', '', '.', '', ' ', ' ', '']
```

but it doesn't group things.  the difference is that this forces a left-to-right order.  if you start trying to do lookbacks you are going to have serious problems with ambiguity, multiple ways to divide `5.2.2` etc.

the above works by matching numbers, or words, but not forming groups.  then, if everything else fails, it matches a piece of junk and tries again.